# How to update state from firebase realtime? | react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an html element that needs to updated every time there is a change in Firebase. What I've done so far is this implement this particular function:

```
componentWillMount() {
    var that = this;
    var updateDb = firebase.database().ref("currentToken");
    updateDb.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        that.setState({ currentToken: snapshot.val() });
    });
    console.log(that.state.currentToken);
    document.getElementById("tokenField").innerHTML = "Current Token: " + that.state.currentToken;
}
```

What is the proper way to update a variable in my app whenever there is a change in Firebase? Kindly give any suggestion to improve my coding as I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out to me is how you're handling `this`. You should be able to use a [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to maintain scope:

```
updateDb.on("value", (snapshot) => {
  this.setState({ currentToken: snapshot.val() });
});
```

The other thing that stands out is

```
document.getElementById("tokenField").innerHTML =
  "Current Token: " + that.state.currentToken;
```

React will not update that element when you call `setState`. React will update any components requiring `state` by calling the `render` method. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but assuming that is a component that you are rendering, you should update it in `render` like this:

```
<div id="tokenField">
    Current token {this.state.currentToken}
</div>
```