# Sockets, long polling, and async in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sockets, polling

I am building an app that will reach out to an api endpoint that returns the following:

```
[
  {batchName: "wqrs1", totalJobs: X1, numErrJobs: Y1, numCmpltJobs: Z1, inFlightJobs: K1},
  {batchName: "wqrs2", totalJobs: X2, numErrJobs: Y2, numCmpltJobs: Z2, inFlightJobs: K2},
  {batchName: "wqrsN", totalJobs: XN, numErrJobs: YN, numCmpltJobs: ZN, inFlightJobs: KN},
]
```

from an api endpoint `/get-all-batches` to show in a dashboard using Reactjs (which I'm very new at). what I am trying to understand is how to update my react store/ state when one of the values X,Y,Z,K changes. can someone differentiate between sockets, long polling, or async/await? is this what I should be looking at to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to this (answer and post): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53749735/2269464. The answer contains helpful insights for you to begin with React.

The most important part is the setState call, once `.on("value"..` triggers.

```
export default ...... extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      currentToken: 'first value'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      var that = this;
      var updateDb = firebase.database().ref("currentToken");
      updateDb.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          that.setState({ currentToken: snapshot.val() });
      });
  }
```

That (setState) would tell the component to re-render so if you have the code below, you will see `first value` first and when firebase fires, you will have the new value re-rendered for you by react:

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.state.currentToken}</div>
}
```